# Convert tfrecords to image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I found a training dataset which is a set of tfrecords files,im trying to convert them into images but with no results,is it possible to convert them to images ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ti7 that's the problem i didn't find any suggested solution for it. 
The only thing is link to dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/satellitevu/satellite-next-day-wildfire-spread?select=tfrecords_updated_filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what is inside a `tf.record` use `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` and `tf.train.Example`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['/content/sv_0_128.tfrecords'])
for batch in ds.take(1):
  example = tf.train.Example()
  example.ParseFromString(batch.numpy())
  print(example)
```

To parse the records, use `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` with `tf.io.parse_single_example` and `tf.io.parse_tensor`:

```
def decode_fn(record_bytes):
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(
      record_bytes,
      {"air_temperature_at_2_metres_1hour_Maximum": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
       "air_temperature_at_2_metres_1hour_Minimum": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
       "elevation": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
       "landcover": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string), 
       "ndvi": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
       "todays_fires": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
       "todays_frp": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
       "tomorrows_fires": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string)}
  )

for batch in ds.map(decode_fn).take(1):
  f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,4)
  rows = np.repeat([0, 1], 4)
  cols = np.repeat([[0, 1, 2, 3]], 2, axis=0).ravel()
  for v, r, c in zip(batch.values(), rows, cols):
    axarr[r,c].imshow(tf.io.parse_tensor(v, out_type=tf.float32), cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Also check the [source code](https://github.com/SatelliteVu/SatelliteVu-AWS-Disaster-Response-Hackathon/blob/442689f2282b44ada05d9d5356a9df3341484be1/deep_learning/datagen.py#L179) of Satellite VU.

Comment: it worked ,Thnk uu soo muchhhhh

Answer (score 0):

Try [tfrmaker](https://pypi.org/project/tfrmaker/), a TFRecord utility package for image datasets. Package can read, write, count and visualize tfrecords. See this [examples](https://github.com/csbasil/tfrmaker/tree/main/examples) for more advanced usages.